# Azure VPN Gateway using OpenVpn and Radius Auth w/ certificate

Tags: azure, certificate, vpn, openvpn, radius

So im currently trying to setup up an azure vpn gateway (VpnGW1) with OpenVpn Protocol and Radius auth. The client should authenticate using a certificate.

I find articles on the individual topics such as cert auth or radius auth, but never a description of how these can be configured together. It is also noticeable that the following PS call is mentioned in the MSDocs during an OpenVPN deployment.

```
$Gateway = Get-AzVirtualNetworkGateway -ResourceGroupName $RG -Name $GWName
 Set-AzVirtualNetworkGateway -VirtualNetworkGateway $Gateway -VpnClientRootCertificates @()
Set-AzVirtualNetworkGateway -VirtualNetworkGateway $Gateway `
-VpnClientAddressPool "172.16.201.0/24" -VpnClientProtocol "OpenVPN" `
-RadiusServerAddress "10.51.0.15" -RadiusServerSecret $Secure_Secret
```

[MSDOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-how-to-radius-ps)

The parameter VpnRootcertificates is specified here. I have also maintained this with the required PublicCertData, unfortunately this data does not appear in the VPN gateway when I call it up via the AZureCLI at Radius Auth.

Has anyone had experience with this scenario. I can find articles on radius auth and certifacte auth but nothing on this special scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to implement Open Vpn with Radius & Certificate Authentication and are unable to find documentation for the same.

Here is a document from Azure Docs that talks about implementing Radius with Certificate Authentication- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-vpn-client-configuration-radius#certeap

You can create VPN client configuration files for RADIUS certificate authentication that uses the EAP-TLS protocol. Typically, an enterprise-issued certificate is used to authenticate a user for VPN. Make sure that all connecting users have a certificate installed on their devices, and that your RADIUS server can validate the certificate.